# History expansion at each iteration it's possible?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to use word designator in a `for` loop.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

set -o history -o histexpand

# exec 2>/dev/null

echo {}
for i in $(seq 4); do
    echo "{!$}"
done
```

In the output i have that the history expansion was only once (When a loop start).

```
{}
    echo "{{}}"
{{}}
{{}}
{{}}
{{}}
```

Sequence of the same commands works properly.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

set -o history -o histexpand

echo {}
echo {!$}
echo {!$}
echo {!$}
echo {!$}
```

```
{}
echo {{}}
{{}}
echo {{{}}}
{{{}}}
echo {{{{}}}}
{{{{}}}}
echo {{{{{}}}}}
{{{{{}}}}}
```

So it is possible to get same result within the loop?

Comment: Not unless you use `eval` to delay evaluation of the history expansion, which occurs *before* parsing, let alone execution.

Comment: What a wonderfully goofy project. And while I expected to get `eval` to work, I tried both `eval echo "{!$}"` and `eval echo '{!$}'` and didn't get the results you require. I was careful to precede the `for` loop with `echo {}`. Good luck!

Comment: Yes, confirmed, `eval echo "{$_}"` gives the results you need. Good luck to all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way (Thanks to [rowboat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18181790)).

```bash
#!/bin/bash

echo {}
for i in $(seq 4); do
    echo {$_}
done
```

Comment: You can accept your own answer and gain valuable reputation points. Cheers